# PyPy C++ API missing Py_Initialize()

Tags: python, c++, pypy

I'm trying to call PyPy from C++. When using CPython, I need to call Py_Initialize() function before calling any other Py_* functions. However, PyPy does not have Py_Initialize() or PyPy_Initialize() functions. How should it be replaced? If I don't have it, my program simply crashes when I try to use any PyPy_* or Py_* function.

Comment: The the docs for [**`cffi`**](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/embedding.html)

Comment: @PeterWood thanks, but I'm looking for an option where I don't need to compile the python code to a dynamically loaded library.

Answer (score 1):

See [this issue](https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/-/issues/3837) in the PyPy issue tracker. There is still a lot to do to make `Py_Initialize` work on PyPy. Help is welcome.